# online Bookmark with full text search?

Tags: bookmarks

Is there a free service to let me bookmark a page and be able to search the full text of my bookmarked pages, like the premium service of diigo?

Answer (score 0):

**[Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/)** does exactly that.

It not only searches the title, url, tags, notes but also every word on the bookmarked page.

Comment: Google Bookmarks do not include page body in the search. A feature as such would require a browser extension – because content on the page user is session specific. Examples of services that do provide this feature are https://historio.us/ and http://fetching.io/.